# vcf file not opening in ios 10

Tags: iphone, ios10

We have developed a code in .net that would send a contact file in VCF format to iphone. This was working fine till ios9, but from ios 10 contacts app in iphone is not recognizing the VCF file. Instead it is displaying in ics format as shown below.

[image]

Below is the code that we are sending in VCF format. Can somebody please help me  on how to save the contact to ios 10.

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Jakubowski;Erica;;;
FN:Erica Jakubowski
ORG:ALL-STATE LEGAL
TITLE:Technical Support Specialist
item1.TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:800.222.0510
item1.X-ABLabel:Work Voice
item2.TEL;TYPE=WORK,FAX:111.111.1111
item2.X-ABLabel:Work Fax
item3.TEL;TYPE=CELL:222.222.2222
item3.X-ABLabel:Work Mobile
item4.EMAIL;type=INTERNET,WORK,PREF:ejakubowsk@aslegal.com
item4.X-ABLabel:Work
item5.ADR;TYPE=WORK,PREF:;;1 Commerce Drive;Cranford;NJ;07016;
item5.X-ABLabel:Work
item6.URL;TYPE=WORK:www.aslegal.com
item6.X-ABLabel:Website
NOTE;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:My=20Mobile=20Business=20Card:=20=0D=0A=0D=0AI=20learned=20more=20about=20Erica=20Jakubowski=20Near=2018=20Sikh=20Rd,=20Jupiter=20Colony,=20Radha=20Swamy=20Colony,=20Bowenpally,=20SC=20on=209/17/2016.=0D=0A=0D=0AFind=20me=20here:=20=0D=0AMy=20LinkedIn=20Profile:=20http://www.linkedin.com/pub/erica-jakubowski/33/392/a02=0D=0AComplimentary=20vizCards:=20www.vizibility.com=0D=0AWhat's=20a=20vizCard?:=20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DgTp4RMe8unw=0D=0AGoogle=20Me:=20https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=3Dchrome-instant&ion=3D1&espv=3D2&ie=3DUTF-8#q=3Dallintext:%22erica+jakubowski%22+%22all-state+legal%22+OR+asl++=0D=0AALL-STATE=20LEGAL:=20http://www.aslegal.com=0D=0Atest:=20www.aslegal.com=0D=0A
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64:;TYPE=PNG:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALQAAAC0CAYAAAA9zQYyAAAAAXNSR0IArs4
END:VCARD